# Pandas Set on copy warning when using .loc

Tags: pandas, copy

I'm trying to change the values in a column of a dataframe based on a condition.

```
In [1]:df.head()
Out[2]:                gen        cont  
timestamp                                                                   
2012-07-01 00:00:00        0.293        0    
2012-07-01 00:30:00        0.315        0    
2012-07-01 01:00:00        0.0          0    
2012-07-01 01:30:00        0.005        0    
2012-07-01 02:00:00        0.231        0
```

I want to set the `'gen'` column to `NaN` whenever the sum of the 2 columns is below a threshold of 0.01, so what I want is this:

```
In [1]:df.head()
Out[2]:                gen        cont  
timestamp                                                                   
2012-07-01 00:00:00        0.293        0    
2012-07-01 00:30:00        0.315        0    
2012-07-01 01:00:00        NaN          0    
2012-07-01 01:30:00        NaN          0    
2012-07-01 02:00:00        0.231        0
```

I have used this:

```
df.loc[df.gen + df.con <0.01 ,'gen'] = np.nan
```

It gives me the result I want but with the warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I am confused because I am using .loc and I think I'm using it in the way suggested.

Comment: That code besides the use of dots to access the columns as attributes looks valid, you must have done something prior to this in order to generate the warning. Did you filter the df prior to these lines

Comment: I did filter the df previously, but the warning is generated by this line. If I execute the line in the console it reproduces the warning

Comment: @doctorer - Can you add your code for filtering? Maybe need `df1 = df.copy()`

Comment: Also, are you saying the use of dots is bad practice?

Comment: @doctorer - Edchum think more general is use `[]` what works nice with column name like `sum`, `mean`.

Comment: Filtering was done like this `df = df_in.loc[sDate:eDate]` so it filtered another dataframe to a specific time period

Comment: Yes please stop doing this and get into the habit of `df.loc[(df['gen'] + df['con']) <0.01 ,'gen'] = np.nan`, it can lead to ambiguous behaviour. Basically if you filtered the df prior to the assignment it raises the warning as the behaviour isn't guaranteed, if you explicitly make a copy then the modifications occur on the copy

Comment: OK, but I get the same result. And the filtering was done explicitly creating a new dataframe so i can't see how that would be the issue.

Comment: I'm commenting on best practices, the issue here is the filtering prior to the assignment, you need to do the filtering and assignment on the same line to get rid of the warning

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand this. I have copied a section of `df_in` to `df`. This is deliberate as I want to leave `df_in` unchanged.  Then the assignment is acting on `df` and is telling me to do what I am doing.

Comment: You need to explicitly call `copy()` in order to make a copy, what you did was to create a reference to a slice of your orig df, hence the warning because you're now using `.loc` which infers that you're intending to work on a view of the df. The warning isn't always accurate but it's highlighting potential problems, the method of accessing columns is a side note

Comment: I get you. Sorry for being slow - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For me your solution works nice.

Alternative solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html), it by default add `NaN` if condition `True`:

```
df['gen'] = df['gen'].mask(df['gen'] + df['cont'] < 0.01)
print (df)
             timestamp    gen  cont
0  2012-07-01 00:00:00  0.293     0
1  2012-07-01 00:30:00  0.315     0
2  2012-07-01 01:00:00    NaN     0
3  2012-07-01 01:30:00    NaN     0
4  2012-07-01 02:00:00  0.231     0
```

EDIT:

You need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html).

If you modify values in `df` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df_in`), and that Pandas does warning.

```
df = df_in.loc[sDate:eDate].copy()
```

Comment: this isn't what the OP wants, they want to remove the warning, they already get the desired result

Comment: @EdChum - sorry, I think it is solution in `EDIT` for it. Or something missing?

Comment: I want to keep df_in unchanged, that's why I copied to a new df.

Comment: Yes, then need `copy`. Another solution is `overwrite` all changed to original `df_in = df_in.loc[sDate:eDate]`, but it is not what you want.

Comment: OK then doing `copy` is the solution, when you stated I get the result I want but generate the warning, I thought you wanted to affect the orig df